# Count lines in multiple text files python

Tags: python, count, rows

I know it has been written a lot on this issue but i still have problems. I have 73 text files with different names in one data directory and i want to count number of rows in each text file. The outcome should include name of the text file and number of rows.

I tried this:

```
def file_lenght(filename, file):
    for filename in os.listdir(data_directory):  
        with open(data_directory + "/" + filename) as file:  
             for i, l in enumerate(file):
                        pass
        return i + 1

print(filename, file_lenght)

data_directory = path of the parent file of all text files
```

But it only prints me out the name of the first file.

Outcome should look something like this:

```
first_text_file: 2268 lines
second_text_file: 2286 lines
etc.
```

Sorry for duplicating the questions, but i was unable to use any of existing codes with this matter.

Comment: What have you tried so far? In what way were the alternatives you found not working for you? This question gives the impression that you simply have a problem you would like solved, and stack overflow is not a code authoring service. If you need someone to write code for you, then I'm sure you can agree a price with someone (maybe on fiverr).

Comment: I think we can reopen the question since the OP has added his code ?

Comment: @kederrac There is no need for that. The question of counting lines in multiple files was asked on SO [multiple times already](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+count+lines+in+multiple+files+site%3Astackoverflow.com). And since this particular question adds nothing useful, IMHO, it will better to delete it altogether.

Answer (score 3):

you can use:

```
def count_lines(file_name):
    with open(filen_name) as f:
        return f'{file_name}: {sum(1 for _ in f)} lines`
```

you are using the built-in function `sum` with a generator expression, the generator expression will give you 1 for each line in your file

---

if you have a list of files you can use:

```
for filename in os.listdir(data_directory):  
    print(count_lines(filename))
```